# Relacionar os indices (chaves) de um obejto Array aos indices (chaves) de um array (PHP)

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, cakephp, phpmyadmin

Estou com uma duvida na qual não obtive solução. Tenho um objeto Array `values` e um array `status`, onde eu quero relacionar os índices do objeto Array `values` aos indices do array `status`. De modo que eu possa escrever um teste lógico onde: **Se o indice `0` do objeto Array `values` for diferente de null (ou seja, contém valor), então o indice `0` do array `status` receberá o valor '1'.**

OU

**Se o indice `1` do objeto Array `values` for diferente de null (ou seja, contém valor), então o indice `1` do array `status` receberá o valor '1'.**

Por exemplo, antes do teste lógico:

```
values:[
 0 => Array1:[
  0 => "1,023"
  1 => "0,023"
  2 => "5,023"
  3 => "1"
 ]
 1 => Array2:[
  0 => "null"
  1 => "null"
  2 => "5"
  3 => "1,365"
 ]
 2 => Array3:[
  0 => "null"
  1 => "null"
  2 => "null"
  3 => "null"
 ]
]


status:[
 0 => "0"
 1 => "0"
 2 => "0"
]
```

Após o teste lógico:

```
status:[
 0 => "1"
 1 => "0"
 2 => "0"
]
```

**Neste exemplo só o indice `0` do array `status` recebeu o valor "1", porque APENAS o array `0` do objeto Array `values` tinha valores diferente de null.**

---

**Observações:**

O array `status` sempre terá o mesmo número de índices que o objeto Array `values` terá de arrays **(Se array `status` tem 5 indices (0, 1, 2, 3, 4), o objeto Array `value` terá 5 arrays (0, 1, 2, 3, 4))**. Além disso o array `status` sempre iniciará com o valor os valores do indice igual a '0'. **E se os valores dos indices do objeto `values` forem TODOS diferentes de null, cada indice do array `status` receberá o valor '1'.**

Exemplificando,

```
status:[
 0 => "1",
 1 => "1",
 2 => "1",
]
```

---

**Eu tentei usar um if para percorrer os indices (chaves) do objeto array `value` e um if para mudar os valores de `status`. Inclusive usei outras variações, mas nada que funcionasse**

```
<?php

foreach ($value as $key => $items) {
  if ($items ==  "null") {
   $status['status'][$key] == "0";
 } else {
   $status['status'][$key] == "1";
 }
}

?>
```

Espero ter sido claro na minha dúvida.
Desde já, agradeço.

Answer (score -1):

Depois de muitos testes e muita leitura da documentação do PHP, consigui resolver o meu problema.

```
foreach ($values as $key => $items) {
    if (in_array(null, $items)) {
        $status['status'][$key] = "0";
    } else {
        $status['status'][$key] = "1";
    }
}
```

Quando dou um `dd($status)` obtenho a confirmação da modificação desejada.

```
"status" => [
 0 => "1"
 1 => "0"
 2 => "0"
]
```